# vba savecopyas: how to open the copied workbook then delete it's VBA Scripts

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have a savecopyas code at an at close prompt code that works, but if someone opens the copied document then trys to close it, the same copied VBA script within itself will try running the savecopyas to it's own path, resulting in an error/debug messagebox.  My first idea would be to open the copied workbook in the background and delete all the VBA scripts then close and save as read only, however I also had a thought maybe I should just try to change the copied workbook to an .xlsx instead of it's original version .xslm format.
Any suggestions?

Here is what I have so far, but my question I guess is how do I open the copied workbook(not the original) and delete the VBA scripts in it in the background(not visible) then save and close?
Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

This is in my 'ThisWorkBook' module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Me.Saved Then
    Msg = "Do you want to save the changes you made to "
    Msg = Msg & Me.Name & "?"
    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
    Select Case Ans
        Case vbYes
            Me.Save
        Case vbNo
            Me.Saved = True
        Case vbCancel
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
      End Select
End If
Call Auto_Save 'Change this to your own subroutine
End Sub
```

This is in my 'Module1':

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim backupfolder As String

backupfolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\John's Backup\"

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupfolder & ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub

Sub Auto_Save()

Dim savedate

savedate = Date

Dim savetime
savetime = Time
Dim formattime As String
formattime = Format(savetime, "hh.MM.ss")
Dim formatdate As String
formatdate = Format(savedate, "DD - MM - YYYY")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim backupfolder As String
backupfolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\John's Backup\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupfolder & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "Backup Run. Please Check at: " & backupfolder & " !"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nailed it - remove the macros by saving the workbook as an xlsx file (assuming you are using Excel 2007+).

If I understand your situation correctly, the workbook backup is saved when the workbook closes. So, I would save the workbook, then `SaveAs` the workbook, and then close the workbook.

One implementation could look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7751653/772086):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
' Note that xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 41
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs backupfolder & ActiveWorkbook.Name, FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Separately, the folder location could fail if a user is on an older version of Windows (or if a future version has a different location for the Documents folder). So, instead of this:

```
backupfolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\John's Backup\"
```

do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751464/language-independent-way-to-get-my-documents-folder-in-vba-excel-2003):

```
Dim WshShell as Object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
backupfolder = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") + "\John's Backup\"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I completely missed the file format:= portion.  Good advise and information.  Cheers.

Comment: Hmm I changed that line you suggested and it comes up with an error:  Compile error: Named argument not found.  ??

Comment: Got it, it works now.  I had to take out the "ActiveWorkbook.Name" and replcae it with the actual document name: "Open_Machine_Schedule.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook  and it worked.  Not sure why it didn't work the other way.